# Implementing news feeds functionality using redux react and feathersJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, feathersjs

Hello I came up with this model for implementing news feeds in my react application. Whenever A user fills a message it must be published to all the users. For that I came up like this

```
Context
-----------------
Intent  ->  corresponding Redux action 
Users can post a feed ->  postFeed() post request to server
All posts should be fetched when component loads -> getFeeds() get request
add new feed to the existing array of feeds when a user posts a feed -> addDataToFeed()
```

Problem I'm facing new post is bring added to the current user's component but the new feed that i just created in not being reflected in another user. (Also another user's store state doesn't reflect the new post that I've added to the existing current array of feeds, but if I reload, getFeeds function gets called and changes are redlecting).

```
const postDataToFeed => async dispatch => {
 try {
    await feedService.on('created', (data) => {
      dispatch({ type: ADD_DATA_TO_FEED, payload: data });
    });
    dispatch(getFeeds());
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(setAlert(err.message, 'danger'));
    dispatch({ type: ADD_DATA_TO_FEED_ERROR });
  }
}
```

Initial State for Feedreducer

```
const initialState = {
  feeds: [],
  feed: null,
  loading: true,
  value: 0,
};
```

FeedReducer

```
 case ADD_DATA_TO_FEED:
      return {
        ...state,
        feeds: [payload, ...state.feeds],
        loading: false,
      };
```

Any guidance on how to implement this real time functionality. I'm using redux-thunk as middleware and feathersJS as backend framework.

Answer (score 0):

From your model, you need something which will inform the other clients that a change has been made.

There are a few strategies, but probably the two most common are either to implement **polling** (make a fetch periodically to get an updated state) or to implement some **publish/subscribe** system.  I've used websockets in the past for that or you can consider a more established protocol like mqtt.

Comment: The ```feathersService.on('created', ...)``` is actually a websocket implementation under the hood. In my backend I get publishing events to all authenticated users.

Comment: You should post the code that's relevant to publishing those events and what dispatches are responding